# No tables are created inside HIVE but data is crerated inside hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop, bigdata

I am new to HDFS and I am trying to import data from my oracle 12c db. I have a table EMP, it needs to be imported inside hdfs as well as hive tables.

My data is getting created inside hdfs ('/user/hdfs' a folder 'EMP' gets created). But when I open hive query editor and type 'show tables' I don't get to see any tables here. I need the tables to be created inside HIVE as well

I am running the following commands.

```
    1. Since am running sqoop as root user
    usermod -a -G supergroup hardik

    2.
    export SQOOP_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop
    export HIVE_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hive

    export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/ojdbc7.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hive/lib/*
    export HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs

    3.
    export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
```

Now am running the SQOOP import command and I get the following on the console

```
    4.

    sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@bigdatadev2:1521/orcl --username BDD1 --password oracle123 --table EMP --hive-import -m 1 --create-hive-table --hive-table EMP

    [root@bigdatadev1 ~]# sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@bigdatadev2:1521/orcl --username BDD1 --password oracle123 --table EMP --hive-import -m 1 --create-hive-table --hive-table EMP
    Warning: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/bin/../lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
    Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
    16/04/07 22:15:23 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.5.1
    16/04/07 22:15:23 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
    16/04/07 22:15:23 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: Using Hive-specific delimiters for output. You can override
    16/04/07 22:15:23 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: delimiters with --fields-terminated-by, etc.
    16/04/07 22:15:23 INFO oracle.OraOopManagerFactory: Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop is disabled.
    16/04/07 22:15:23 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
    16/04/07 22:15:23 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
    16/04/07 22:15:24 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
    16/04/07 22:15:24 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM EMP t WHERE 1=0
    16/04/07 22:15:24 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
    Note: /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/fcb6484db042a7b4295d911956145a4e/EMP.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    16/04/07 22:15:25 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/fcb6484db042a7b4295d911956145a4e/EMP.jar
    16/04/07 22:15:25 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
    16/04/07 22:15:25 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
    16/04/07 22:15:25 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of EMP
    16/04/07 22:15:25 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
    16/04/07 22:15:25 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
    16/04/07 22:15:26 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
    16/04/07 22:15:26 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at bigdata/10.103.25.39:8032
    16/04/07 22:15:30 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation
    16/04/07 22:15:30 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
    16/04/07 22:15:30 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1460040138373_0007
    16/04/07 22:15:31 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1460040138373_0007
    16/04/07 22:15:31 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://bigdata:8088/proxy/application_1460040138373_0007/
    16/04/07 22:15:31 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1460040138373_0007
    16/04/07 22:15:37 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1460040138373_0007 running in uber mode : false
    16/04/07 22:15:37 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
    16/04/07 22:15:43 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1460040138373_0007_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
    Error: EMP : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    16/04/07 22:15:56 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1460040138373_0007_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
    Error: EMP : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    16/04/07 22:16:03 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
    16/04/07 22:16:04 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1460040138373_0007 completed successfully
    16/04/07 22:16:04 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 31
        File System Counters
            FILE: Number of bytes read=0
            FILE: Number of bytes written=137942
            FILE: Number of read operations=0
            FILE: Number of large read operations=0
            FILE: Number of write operations=0
            HDFS: Number of bytes read=87
            HDFS: Number of bytes written=12
            HDFS: Number of read operations=4
            HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
            HDFS: Number of write operations=2
        Job Counters 
            Failed map tasks=2
            Launched map tasks=3
            Other local map tasks=3
            Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=20742
            Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
            Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=20742
            Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=20742
            Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=10619904
        Map-Reduce Framework
            Map input records=3
            Map output records=3
            Input split bytes=87
            Spilled Records=0
            Failed Shuffles=0
            Merged Map outputs=0
            GC time elapsed (ms)=53
            CPU time spent (ms)=2090
            Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=207478784
            Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=2169630720
            Total committed heap usage (bytes)=134217728
        File Input Format Counters 
            Bytes Read=0
        File Output Format Counters 
            Bytes Written=12
    16/04/07 22:16:04 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 12 bytes in 38.6207 seconds (0.3107 bytes/sec)
    16/04/07 22:16:04 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 3 records.
    16/04/07 22:16:05 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
    16/04/07 22:16:05 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM EMP t WHERE 1=0
    16/04/07 22:16:05 INFO hive.HiveImport: Loading uploaded data into Hive

    Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/jars/hive-common-1.1.0-cdh5.5.1.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
    FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. AlreadyExistsException(message:Table EMP already exists)
```

I have tried all variations of sqoop import commands but none have succeeded. I am even more confuse today. Please help. Please do not mark this as duplicate.

Comment: Hadoop distribution is still running on JDK6 or JDK 7?

Answer (score 0):

From your logs, I found two errors:

1. > Error: EMP : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 comes when you are trying to run a class compiled using Java 1.8 compiler into a lower JRE version e.g. JRE 1.7 or JRE 1.6. Check [more](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/05/fixing-unsupported-majorminor-version.html#ixzz45V8xZBYC) here.

2. > FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. AlreadyExistsException(message:Table EMP already exists)

Your job worked till taking data to hdfs. You must be trying same command again without deleting this `/user/hdfs/EMP` directory. That's why you got this error.

Check this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21189207/3929393).

Comment: Hadoop distribution is working on 7. Is it because of this that it's giving major minor issue?

Comment: @HardikGupta what's your `java –version`?

Comment: Java version 1.8.0.72

Comment: thats the problem. **Sqoop auto-generates class definitions to deserialze the data from the database to read metadata about databases and tables.** check more details [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/06/introducing-sqoop/). your java code is compiled with Java 8 thats creating major-minor issue.

Comment: Dev am sorry but my hadoop is on version 8

Comment: Also my Mar reduce jobs work.. and the data gets stored inside hdfs. The issue is hive tables are not getting created

Comment: add `-verbose` at the end of your query and make sure you deleted target dir. Let me know what you find

Comment: Hi dev.. can you share your email id with me, I'll send you the log file.. its too big

Comment: you can mail me at dev.emr@gmail.com

Comment: as per your logs  **Create statement: CREATE TABLE `EMP` ( `EMP_ID` STRING, `EMP_NAME` STRING) COMMENT 'Imported by sqoop on 2016/04/11 19:32:29' ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\001' LINES TERMINATED BY '\012' STORED AS TEXTFILE
16/04/11 19:32:29 DEBUG hive.TableDefWriter: Load statement: LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs://bigdata:8020/user/hdfs/EMP' INTO TABLE `EMP`
16/04/11 19:32:29 INFO hive.HiveImport: Loading uploaded data into Hive** there is no error in create table and load data statement. You sure you are looking for `emp` (_in small letters_) in `default` schema

Comment: Interestingly it shows this error: Execution error return code 1 from organic. Apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTASK.  Already exists exception (message: Table EMP already exists) . Now when I do show tables in hive query editor or select * from default.emp it gives me error no table found. But data is present inside hdfs in the path /user/hive/warehouse/new